# Manipulate HTML from server-side scripts

Tags: jquery, html, google-apps-script

I am trying to manipulate the HTML of an Add-On for Google Docs from server-side Google Apps Script, but have not found a method that supports it.  I would like to add elements when a button is clicked.

Is this possible, or can the HTML only be changed by client-side JavaScript or jQuery?

Comment: Your question isn't explicit. Do you mean after page load manipulations?

Comment: @Jonathon Yes. I would like to add elements when a button is clicked.

Comment: I edited your question to be a bit more general, in the hope that would make it more useful for a broader audience.

Answer (score 1):

All client-side manipulations and interactions have to be done with client-side JavaScript. You can have that code interact with the apps script backend but the actual manipulation needs to be driven within the sandbox.

The button click could simply send a call to GAS which returns either data or fully formed html (recommend the former) interpreting that and adding it to the page is then handled in a success handler callback. [google.run methods](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#methods)

Beware overuse of jQuery, a great deal of what it brings to the party can be done with vanilla js I modern browsers.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you give me an example of a success handler callback?

Comment: Worth noting that Google Apps Script is no different than any other client / server web application in this respect. The server side code provides the initial HTML page to the browser client; after that, any visible changes are done in the browser. FWIW, jQuery never did anything that vanilla JS couldn't do (obvious, since it's implemented in JS).

Comment: jQuery handled edge case browser compatibilities behind a single API which was what got its traction I think. That early Ajax and simple DOM transforms.